# Storing results in a variable in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

for my homework I've have the following task:
I've got a simple database which is like facebook with friends and their relations.
Now I have to count the number of direct friends and the number of the friends of the direct friends.

**So my approach was**:
Selecting all direct friends and store their ids's in a variable.
Then I iterate over these ids and store all direct friends of the current user in another variable. (For each in the same). In the end I've got a big array with alle the related user id's. Then I just have to select distinct the id's and count them.

My Problem is:
How do I store the id's in a variable (array?) so that I can easily loop over them and in the end do a distinct select of the id's?

Hope you can give me a hint on that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the assignment does not require the use of plpgsql, it can be solved more easily with plain **SQL**.

Given this table (which you should have provided):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE f (
   friend_of int
  ,friend_with int
  ,PRIMARY KEY (friend_of, friend_with)
);
```

How many friends does user 1 have?

```
SELECT count(*) As friends
FROM   f
WHERE  friend_of = 1;
```

How many unique friends do the friends of user 1 have (excluding user 1 himself)?

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT f2.friend_with) - 1 AS friends_friends -- minus himself
FROM   f f1
JOIN   f f2 ON f2.friend_of = f1.friend_with
WHERE  f1.friend_of = 1;
```

Without `DISTINCT` common friends would be counted multiple times.
[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8272c/2)